# How to sort a JTable when it is created

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, rowsorter

Say I have a table that the first column is id, and I want the table to be sorted by id number  when it is created. What can I do?

I hope 'sorting before the construction of the table' is not the only solution.

Comment: show us your  efforts pls

Comment: @shreyanshjogi I just went over the JTable page and looked at every method contains 'sort', and searched 'default', 'JTable', 'sort' as the keywords here. And then I posted it.

Comment: post some of you code here

Comment: @shreyanshjogi I don't think the question needs a piece of code to be answered, it is that people requires the code as 'the proof of effort'. Now the table is there, I set all the colunm classes to Integer, all I need is a method to sort the table in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code

```
JTable table = new JTable();
table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
table.getRowSorter().toggleSortOrder(0);
```

Comment: That works, and you can sort in reverse order by calling the method twice.